# Can't create font file in MikTeX

Tags: fonts

I wanted to add a nice skull symbol, using the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\font\omding=omding
\scalebox{5}{\omding  \char194}
\end{document}
```

But pdflatex gives an error:

> ! Font \f@ttestfont=omding at 9.99893pt not loadable: Metric (TFM)
>   file not found.

Here is my pdflatex version:

```
pdflatex --version
MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.4225 (1.40.12) (MiKTeX 2.9)
```

On Linux with TexLive:

```
pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011)
```

it gives this nice symbol:

[image]

How can I make it work with MikTeX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited this answer because a comment of the op.

Please try this MWE on MIKTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{skull} % for \skull
\begin{document}
$\skull$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahh, I probably didn't explain the problem well. I updated the question. I needed only the skull symbol, not the table.

Comment: Then you need a font for MiKTeX including this symbol. I fear you have to search with `texdoc symbols-a4` for the correct font and package ...

Comment: I tried it. It gives a black skull. And I wanted a white one :). I'll try to search for the font. Or install TeXLive on Windows.

Comment: What do you think about generating a standalone pdf/ps with this symbol in Linux, and using it instead of installing the font? pdf is a vector format, so there shouldn't be any scaling problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble compiling a document which was using the `omding` font using TeX Live on Linux. It's part of the `omega` package. Installing that solved the issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.